# EasyUI and Foundation conflict

Tags: zurb-foundation, jquery-easyui

I am using both products and cannot get rid of a conflict between these. I was told on the Foundation forum that it is because of some css classes being named the same. Has anyone experienced the same problem and figured out a fix? You can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x270Lh7c/

if you add:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css'>
```

Thanks

Comment: On jsfiddle you need to add external resources in the left sidebar. Don't add the `<head>` and `<html>` tags. You only need to add what's inside the `<body>` tags.

Comment: Perhaps, but in my application that link is in the head section.

Comment: It adds the external resources in the head for you, that's how jsfiddle works. Update your jsfiddle and I will be glad to help.

Comment: You need to edit your answer with the updated link to the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/x270Lh7c/5/

Answer (score 1):

If you use Foundation Sass you can choose only the pieces of the Foundation CSS that you want to use in your project. I would suggest doing this and not importing the Foundation tables styling.

Comment: Good point. You can also load the EasyUI sheet after Foundation and any conflicting styles will be overridden by EasyUI's styles.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. The styles are not conflicting, the problem is that Foundation adds a bunch of styles to tables that are not defined in easyUI styles.

Comment: You can not load foundation form styling.

Comment: Right, which is basically what my answer said.

Comment: So what's the problem now?

Comment: No problem, I was just saying in my first reply that what you suggested of loading Foundation first doesn't work and then you suggested the same thing as my answer. Hopefully OP got it sorted out.